# Revision Control Header on your code - automatic, or manually placed?

Tags: svn, version-control

this question may sound really really noob, but I will ask anyway.
I am starting some of my personal software projects and would like to put them on SVN repository.

For the files, I was wondering if the header (exmaple below) is something I have to manually place? Or is the revision control doing that?
I haven't seen any other format but all the files at work the header looks like this.

```
/** @file

    @brief          Write and read all Slices Ace controlled registers
                    These registers are not scan controlled and need dedicated production test. 

    @par Test Desc: 

    @par Requirements:
                    - Calibrated CTE, 
                    - Write and read all ace controlled cte registers (aaaa/5555)
                    - 10MHz ext clock, used as input for the DFLL

    @par Inputs from tester:
                    None
                    One tester sync after clock switch

    @par Inputs read from header file:    
                    Default slice configuration                                    

    @par WS data: None
                  pass/fail 


    @par FT data: None
                  pass/fail 

    $Author: username $
    $Date: 2014-06-03 20:20:05 +0800 (Tue, 03 Jun 2014) $
    $Revision: 249631 $
    $HeadURL: http://www.something.com/files/file.c $

**/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next part was filled by Subversion:

```
$Author: username $
$Date: 2014-06-03 20:20:05 +0800 (Tue, 03 Jun 2014) $
$Revision: 249631 $
$HeadURL: http://www.something.com/files/file.c $
```

see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html for details

Comment: Thanks @Sergey so this means that i don't have to add that last part in the file...

Comment: "so this means that i don't have to add that last part in the file". Not exactly. Subversion not add these lined, but only fill values between $$. You still should add $Author$, $Date$ and so on.  In addition you should apply svn:keywords for this file. Only after this Subversion will expand $Date$ into what you see in header.

Comment: Thanks Guys! Appreciate your answers!